# Android: is there any chart library which can edit graph by dragging points?

Tags: android, charts

I have searched on github and found several chart libraries which are very handy, but none of them support dragging the points to edit. Does anyone know if there are such libraries? Great thanks!

Comment: Are you open to using web view?

Comment: after days of work, I implemented this draggable chart view, based on MPAndroidChart:)